# how to extract scope information from Eclipse JDT core batch compiler

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction, eclipse-jdt

What I want to achieve is extract language structure of source code, for example

```
class Test {
    String name;           // (1)
    Test(String name) {    // (2)
        this.name = name;  // (3) (4)
    }

    String toString() {
        return name;       // (5)
    }
}
```

I want to figure out what is each "name" refering to. Like (3) and (5) are refering to (1) and (4) is refering to (2).
another example is

```
Test t = new Test("t");
System.out.println(t);
```

I want to know `t` is type `Test` and where is it declared.

I use JDT batch compiler (ecjsrc-4.3) downloaded from [Eclipse 4.3 release](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.3-201306052000/) for this task. The reason I choose this instead of whole JDT framework is because there is an existed `JDTCompilerAdapter` of this compiler for Ant, which is what I need in the future.

So far I add a custom AstVisitor at line 540 in `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler`, where compiler already generate AstTree and scope information for all files.

My problem is, I don't know how to use the `scope` in each `visit` method in AstVisitor to get those information. Like in the first example, in line `this.name = name;`. on the LHS, it's a `FieldReference` for `this.name` and a `ThisReference` for `this`. There is no AstNode for `name` on the LHS, therefore I have no idea how to get which field is it referring to. On the RHS, it's a `SingleNameReference`. However if I first invoke `node.resolve(scope)` then try to print out `'node.resolvedType` and `node.binding`, what I'll get is `null` and `java.lang.String name`. Since both argument and field are `String`, I can't distinguish between them.

In second example, I don't know how to get the type information of `t` either, I could only get `null` for `resolveType` and `<no type> t` for `binding`.

Any one have done this before?